# PHP doesn't sort as expected

Tags: php

I am trying to find keywords from a text file, when the keywords are found I provide a score of 1 for each match. The program below counts the score efficiently but doesn't sort the score from higher to lower. Please provide me a solution for this problem.

Here is the code:

```
           <?php
              $lines = file("Abstract.txt");
              $Result = array();
              $index = 0;
              $search_term1= "Tamoxifen";
              $search_term2="Doxorubicin";
              $search_term3="Synergistic";
              $search_term4="MCF-7";
                $search_term5="Inhibition";


        $keywords = array($search_term1, $search_term2, $search_term3);
        $replace_keyword = array("<b>".$search_term1."</b>", "<b>".$search_term2."</b>", "<b>".$search_term3."</b>");

        foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) 
        {
            if($line_num > 1)
                {
                $arr = explode("\t", $line); //Reads tab separated file
                $Pubmed = trim((string)$arr[0]); //first column is Pubmed
                $title = trim((string)$arr[1]); //second column is title
                $abstract = trim((string)$arr[2]); //third column is abstract
                $score = substr_count(strtoupper($title), strtoupper($search_term1)) + substr_count(strtoupper($abstract), strtoupper($search_term1)); //counts occurrence of 1st string in title & abstract
                $score += (substr_count(strtoupper($title), strtoupper($search_term2)) + substr_count(strtoupper($abstract), strtoupper($search_term2))); //counts occurrence of 2nd string in title & abstract
                $score += (substr_count(strtoupper($title),strtoupper($search_term3)) + substr_count(strtoupper($abstract), strtoupper($search_term3))); //counts occurrence of 3rd string in title & abstract


                //store the result as well as data into array 
                    $Result[$index]["Pubmed"] = $Pubmed;
                    $Result[$index]["<BR>score"] = $score; 
                    $Result[$index]["<BR>title"] = str_ireplace($keywords, $replace_keyword, $title);
                    $Result[$index]["<BR>abstract"] = str_ireplace($keywords, $replace_keyword, $abstract);
                    $index++;
                }
        }


            //sort the array by score
            $sorter=array();
            $ret=array();
            reset($Result);
            $key = "score";
            foreach ($Result as $ii => $va) {
            $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
        }
            arsort($sorter);
            foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
            $ret[$ii]=$Result[$ii];
        }
            $Result=$ret;

            foreach($Result as $instance)
        {
            $keys = array_keys($instance);
                foreach($keys as $key)
                {
                    if(!strcmp($key,"abstract")) 
                    echo "\n<b>".$key."</b> : ".$instance[$key]."\n";
                else
                echo "<b>".$key."</b> : ".$instance[$key]."\n";
        }
                echo "\n\n_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\n\n";

        }



        ?>
```

Comment: please provide a *minimalistic* code which is *just* enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What does the result look like and what do you want it to look like?

Comment: @jeroen: I have around 400 articles each has Pubmed id, title and Abstracts. I am trying to search for keywords in the articles and calculate a score for each match. The program below calculates the score but doesn't sort it. The result should be like $Pubmed <BR> $Score <BR> $Title <BR> $Abstracts, now this will be for all the 400 articles I just want the articles with higher score to be at the top followed by lower scores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bad row is:
`$key = "score";`

as you save the score in:
`$Result[$index]["&lt;BR>score"] = $score;`

it should be:
`$key = "<BR>score";`